# I'm stumped by what I think is a glitch in some code when trying to make a circular gauge

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code to build a circular gauge: https://codepen.io/Hiswe/pen/evCxr but when I change the values in the markup code the gauge doesn't change between 50 and 60%. i.e. if the html figures are changed from 66 to 59 in the markup example and the css is similarly altered it doesn't matter what angle is set, the gauge stays stuck on 50 / 180 degrees.

It does this for all values between 50 and 59. Any ideas anyone?

```css
/*h2:nth-of-type(1), section:nth-of-type(1), h2:nth-of-type(2), section:nth-of-type(2) {
display: none;
}*/

.gauge-markup {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #335;
  text-indent: -999em;
  margin: .5em;
}

.gauge-markup::before {
  content: attr(data-fill);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-indent: 0;
}

.gauge-markup,
.gauge-markup span,
.gauge-markup span::before,
.gauge-markup span::after {
  border-radius: 10em;
}

.gauge-markup span,
.gauge-markup span::before,
.gauge-markup span::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Container clipping handling */

.gauge-markup[data-fill^="6"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill^="7"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill^="8"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill^="9"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill^="10"] span {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto)
}

.gauge-markup span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill="6"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill="7"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill="8"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill="9"] span,
.gauge-markup[data-fill="10"] span {
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
}

.gauge-markup span::before,
.gauge-markup span::after {
  border: 1em solid #335;
  content: '';
  clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
}

.gauge-markup span::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/* All the values can be computed by a css pre processor loop */

.gauge-markup[data-fill="0"] span::before {
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="6"] span::before {
  transform: rotate(10.8deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="25"] span::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="33"] span::before {
  transform: rotate(151.2deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="50"] span::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="59"] span::after {
  transform: rotate(-144.8deg)
}

.gauge-markup[data-fill="75"] span::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

```html
<h2>Any size, transparent background but additional markup</h2>
<section>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="0">0 <span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="6">6 <span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="25">25<span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="33">33<span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="50"> 50 <span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="59">59<span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="75">75<span /></div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" data-fill="100">100<span /></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did start out trying to understand the code given and so answer the question as set.

However, I found it very complex in relation to what it was trying to achieve - especially as it would require some preprocessing for the various values, and it had an extra span element in the HTML which was otherwise redundant. It also put the number in the gauge using content in a pseudo element in order to center it which is clever but unnecessary nowadays.

So here's a suggestion for a simpler method. Each gauge has its value set but as a CSS variable (--pc - percentage) rather than a data- attribute. This is then used by CSS to calculate the number of degrees required so we don't need any preprocessing.

The arcs and the semi-opaque background are drawn by a combination of conic and radial gradients on each gauge.

Theoretically having the percentage twice is redundant, as we could pick up again on the idea of putting the value into the gauge using a pseudo element, but this might harm accessibility so both are left in.

```css
.gauge-markup {
  --bg: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  --border: #335;
  --deg: calc((var(--pc) * 360deg) / 100);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid var(--border);
  margin: .5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image: radial-gradient(var(--bg) 0, var(--bg) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(white 0, white 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), conic-gradient(var(--border) 0, var(--border) var(--deg), var(--bg) var(--deg), var(--bg) 360deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 0">0</div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 6">6</div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 25">25</div> 
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 33">33</div> 
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 50">50</div> 
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 59">59</div> 
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 75">75</div>
  <div class="gauge-markup" style="--pc: 100">100</div>
</section>
```